# Implement security token exchange in WS-Security in PHP

Tags: php, ws-security

I am trying to communicate with a web service that is developed by .NET, and I am writing my client in PHP. One of the headache right now, is generating the SignatureValue and  for SignedInfo.

```
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <SignedInfo>
                <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#hmac-sha1"/>
                <Reference URI="#_0">
                    <Transforms>
                        <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                    </Transforms>
                    <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                    <DigestValue>CwMGnFZklO7XsDfFguzl0tw7iHM=</DigestValue>
                </Reference>
            </SignedInfo>
            <SignatureValue>nXJEN8p1nupMA/00TK03VZlADkU=</SignatureValue>
```

There was an Entropy sent to the server and and Entropy received from the server...
Sent to server:

```
<t:Entropy>
                    <t:BinarySecret u:Id="uuid-6d32fbfc-2a74-422f-8b0b-3089db58f6ec-1" 
                        Type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/Nonce">
                        grrlUUfhuNwlvQzQ4bV6TT3wA8ieZPltIf4+H7nIvCE=
                    </t:BinarySecret>
                </t:Entropy>
```

received from server:

```
<t:Entropy>
                <t:BinarySecret u:Id="uuid-8aebe294-15d0-4233-a3b1-ddd9a0d43d98-4"
                    Type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/trust/Nonce">
                    YLABh3ZmZyiO5gvVLZe9J4JPd9w59KGeTFwE85XlzxE=

                    </t:BinarySecret>
                </t:Entropy>
```

From what I read, I am suppose to use PSHA1 to generate a shared key and then run HMAC_SHA1 on the conocalized SignedInfo to generate signed value. Using these two entropies, the expected value is `nXJEN8p1nupMA/00TK03VZlADkU=` but I could never generate that...

My parameter to psha1_derive is `psha1_derive($entropySentByMe (as $secret), 'WS-SecureConversationWS-SecureConversation', $entropyReturnedByServer (as $seed), '' (as timestamp), and length is 32 (256 bits));`

If anyone has more information on how to use PSHA1 to derive the shared key or how to generate the signature value, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

There is an npm module for node.js to make a shared secret using the PSHA1 algorithm to obtain the computed key. [GitHub Link](https://github.com/leandrob/node-psha1).

Comment: This wont help you but just for Node.js developers out there that might encounter "soap the almighty".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).